Will the query time increase?
I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to DB Administration, so, please take it easy!
I have a MySQL database. In which there are about 100 tables. Right now, each table has approximately 50 rows. So, when it comes to select one row from those rows, the query time is about 0.0004 seconds.
Now, for my question: Suppose one of those tables grow and have about 5 million rows. Then if I want to select only 1 row from that table, will its query time increase? By approx how much?
If yes, then What can I do to reduce query time after the table grows?
A bit context of table: Each table has around 10 to 11 columns. Out of which around 4 to 5 are integers of length 11, and 1 column is longtext and others are varchar of length 255.

will its query time increase? It may with high probability (but not 100%). What can I do to reduce query time after the table grows? Proper indexing must help.

@Akina I don't know anything about indexing, can you please guide me how to properly index table?

If you want to use SQL then you MUST read and study at least a base. The indexing is a part of this. In two words - the index by definite expression is separate sorted structure which increases row searching process for matched searching criteria sets.

will its query time increase?, in my experience always it does , as the table  grows larger and larger. I can not tell if it will be 1 or 5 million of rows. What can I do to reduce query time after the table grows?, as already mentioned usually on most cases proper indexing would be the fix

Thank you Akina and Ergest Basha for help. I will surely consider proper indexing in future.

Know about INDEXes!  Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE so we can see the indexes (including PRIMARY KEY) and the SELECT so we can judge whether an index will be used.

@RickJames Thank you for guiding me about INDEXES. Right Now, for each table, I have set its first column (integer of length 11) to PRIMARY KEY and AUTO_INCREMENT. So, if I want to search all the rows whose first column is greater than 10 but less than 10000, so it will be lot efficient to search rather than using that column without PRIMARY KEY. Am I right?

Think of a telephone book.
Does it take longer to search for a name if a telephone book for a larger city, with thousands or millions of people?
Yes, of course it does.
But doubling the number of names in the book doesn't double the time it takes to search for a name. We don't search a telephone book cover to cover. We take advantage of the fact that names are in alphabetical order.
Searching in a sorted set can be done much more efficiently than searching from front to back. We start in the middle, see if the name we are searching for is alphabetically before or after the entry in the middle, and this eliminates half of the book in one step.
Then we look at the midway point in the half we know contains the name we are searching, and again check if the name is before or after the entry at that midpoint. Again, we can eliminate half of what remains in one step.
Continue this method until you find the name. This may require halving the search until it's just one name.
This is searching by binary subdivision, and it takes as many steps as the log-based-2 of the number of names in the book.
Doubling the size of the book only increases the number of steps by (at most) one more "halving."
This is what indexes do for us. A larger book does take longer to search, but only by a little bit.
To learn more about this, I recommend my presentation How to Design Indexes, Really.
There's a video of me giving this presentation on YouTube https://youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU.

First of all, Thank you for such a simple explanation. Now, my question is, if I set one column, say message_id, in the messages table as PRIMARY_KEY and AUTO_INCREMENT, then it will be lot easier to perform search operations in that table. Right?

If your query is searching for the row with a specific value of message_id, then yes, defining that primary key would make the search more specific. If you needed to search based on a different criterion, for example the date or the user who posted the message, then you would need another index. Unlike a telephone book, a database table can have multiple indexes, each to support different queries.

Thank for help. I will keep that in mind in future.

Will it increase?  Almost certainly.
By how much?  As with all things, it depends.
If you are finding rows by a single values on a uniquely-indexed field, the query can use an index (possibly the ne under the Primary Key) so the access will be fast.
If you are finding rows by some other, less efficient, manner (say varchar/text fields with leading wildcards, e.g. like "%FRED", then the query will probably Table Scan...   and reading 5M rows sequentially will take a while.
Most importantly, we can only suggest and guess.
You can find out definitively by TESTING it.  (Yes; testing's not just for Developers!)
Create yourself a "test" database, load it up with [test] data and try it.
Look at the Explain Plans for the query and then start tuning.
There is no "simple answer" for database query tuning.  You just have to get in there and try things out.

Thank you for your help. I will surely look into different ways for tuning my database.
